# Why does JavaScript's map and parseInt function return NaN every other call?

Tags: javascript

When running

```
["6", "1", "0", "3", "3"].map(parseInt)
```

in the JavaScript console in my browser, I get the output

```
[6, NaN, 0, NaN, 3]
```

!  But I was expecting

```
[6, 1, 0, 3, 3]
```

.

It seems that this *might* have to do with the fact that parseInt *can* accept two arguments instead of one.  I was under the impression that `map` merely called the given function on each element of the array separately.  Can somebody clarify how map works and why it leads to this odd behavior?

Comment: `["6", "1", "0", "3", "3"].map(v => parseInt(v))` seems to work. not sure why it doesn't work with just the function.

Comment: Try this: ["6", "1", "0", "3", "3"].map(v => parseInt(v, 10));

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate.  I would not have created this question if I had found the other one during my initial search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `parseInt` accepts two parameters: string integer and base. At the same time, `map` passes two arguments: value and index.

So, basically your call is equivalent to this:

```
["6", "1", "0", "3", "3"].map((value, index) => parseInt(value, index))
```

which results into `NaN` when it is not possible to parse it with given parameters.

Particularly:

- `parseInt("6", 0)` is working, because it seem to use default base (10)
- `parseInt("1", 1)` is failing, because 1 is invalid base
- `parseInt("0", 2)` is working, it is a binary representation of decimal 0
- `parseInt("3", 3)` is failing, because there can be no "3" in base 3
- `parseInt("3", 4)` is working, it is a 4-base representation of decimal 3

Comment: This is a great explanation.  It only lacks a link to the [map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) where you can verify that `map` passes in 3 arguments (or 2 if it can't (or 1 if it can't)) to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because parseInt is `parseInt(string, radix);`

And when map runs it returns the arguments `(value, index, array)`

so it is being run as

```
parseInt("6", 0);
parseInt("1", 1);
parseInt("0", 2);
parseInt("3", 3);
parseInt("3", 4);
```